# Is there any way to silence the reporting in the 'Info' window when deleting objects with a script?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm working on an addon that adds or deletes objects. Sometimes this can be hundreds of objects. The problem is upon deleting 100 objects, the Info editor is filled with 100 lines of `bpy.ops.object.delete()` and the System Console is filled with 100 lines of "Info: Deleted 1 object(s)".

Is there any way to hide or silence this deletion?

```
if self.objects:
    for i in self.objects:
        ob = [self.scn.objects[i]]
        bpy.ops.object.delete({"selected_objects": ob})
        self.objects = []
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using operator `bpy.ops.object.delete()`, you can try next code:

```
import bpy 
object_to_delete = bpy.data.objects['object_name_to_delete']
bpy.data.objects.remove(object_to_delete, do_unlink=True)
```

In this case, you get no messages about the object's deleting.